# Use Site A IP prefix at Site B

Tags: networking, ip, routing, centos-7, gre

I'm currently has two VMs and installed CentOS 7.
These are configuration (All IP address is not real, just for easy  reading)

Machine A :

- Has public IP 61.75.1.201/32
- Announcing IP prefix 112.213.1.0/24 via BIRD daemon
- Has private IP 10.0.0.1/31 and connected with Machine B via GRE tunnel

Machine B :

- Has public IP 59.1.2.20/32
- Has private IP 10.0.0.2/31 and connected with Machine A via GRE tunnel

All configurations are tested and working well.

The problem is:
I want to use 112.213.1.0/24 IP prefix in Machine B. First I tried adding static route in Machine A (112.213.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev tun0), but it looks not working.

As I’m newbie at networking, I don’t have any clue for solve this problem.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You should give us the output of `ip route` on A and on B. Could you confirm the 112.213.1.0 network is directly linked to A. If this is true, the static route should be entered on B, not A.

Comment: Is your GRE tunnel actually called "tun0"? (as opposed to gre0 or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it's not enough to route the prefix to the system; the system has to send packets *from* the prefix through the tunnel the same way. Most likely Machine B's default gateway rejects those packets as "spoofed".

Create a new routing table on Machine B and add a policy rule to use it:

```
ip -4 route add default dev tun0 table 112
ip -4 rule add pref 1000 from 112.213.1.0/24 lookup 112
```